# Infopath Field "From Field" Unavailable

Tags: email, templates, designer, infopath

I am trying to create an Email Template using MS-Office InfoPath and need to have the email template sent from a group email and not myself. Unfortunately Infopath only allows me to use the fields "To:", "CC:", "Bcc:", "Subject" (I don't see the "From" field)

Is there a way I can put this in?

Just an FYI, this is what I am doing.

1) Infopath designer
2) New "Blank Form" 
3) "Design Form" 
4) "Data" tab
5) To E-mail.

Checked all over the net but getting the feeling Infopath does not allow this. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Using the default `EmailSubmitConnection` will not give you a "From" field.

As far as I know; because InfoPath uses Outlook to submit the form it will send it from the default account so it will be "From" that account. It wouldn't be necessary to include a "From" field on the `DataConnection` in this case because it is automatically completed when the form is sent.

If you really want to send from an alternative account then you will need to look into using either the [Outlook interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx) or manually create and send the email using [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.aspx).

Either way you will have to use code so you may want to re-evaluate what you are trying to achieve unless you are already able and willing to code your own solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Dave. Frankly I didn't think Infopath offered such option by default, but just wanted to ask experts just in case I was overlooking something. Anyways, no problem, I don't plan to write code in infopath just to do this, instead I created forms within outlook to achieve this. Really appreciate your advise.